# Hook to compare the already saved value of moderation state of node and updated value

Tags: 8, entities, hooks, workflows

I'm using Workflow state on a content type.
What is the correct HOOK should I use in my custom module to check if the workflow state of the node changed from value to another value to add some actions.

Answer (score 0):

I Used [hook_entity_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/8.2.x) and compared values by using  `$entity->original`

and `$entity`